# Prevent javascript firing on load page

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I have MVC application with JavaScript in the body of the cshtml page. In Model, I have a method that returns a string, and I want that string to add in some div on a page on click of a button. It works, but, the method is triggered every time I load the page (and I want it to be triggered only on click.

Here is code:

Model:

```
public class TestJS
{
        public string Tekst1 { get; set; }
        public string Tekst2 { get; set; }

        public TestJS()
        {
            Tekst1 = "one";
            Tekst2 = "two";
        }

        public string AddTekst()
        {
            return "three (additional text from method)";
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public class TestJSController : Controller
        {
        // GET: TestJS
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.TestJS tjs = new Models.TestJS();
            return View(tjs);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model TestJavaScript.Models.TestJS

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function faddtekst() {
            whr = document.getElementById("div3");
            var t = '@Model.AddTekst()';
            whr.innerHTML += t;
    }
</script>


<h2>Testing JavaScript Firing</h2>

<p>
    First to fields:
    @Model.Tekst1;
    <br />
    @Model.Tekst2;
</p>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Click to show Tekst3" onclick="faddtekst()" />
</form>
<br />
<hr />
<div id="div3">

</div>
```

I tried to wrap JS in `$(document).ready()` with same result.

Somebody may think of this as a strange approach, but, a model method that I'm trying to execute takes over 10 seconds in real code, so, I want to prevent waiting every time page loads (waiting should be only if the user clicks button).

The strangest thing is that `Model.AddTekst()` is executed EVEN if I comment it in javascript function with '//'.

Anyone knows how to avoid unwanted execution of `Model.Method`?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are experiencing is not strange at all. `@Model.AddText()` executes on the backend once the view is compiled which is normal behaviour.

A comment in razor would look like this

```
@* Comment goes here *@
```

But this is not what you want to achieve.

I'm afraid your approach wont work since you can't execute a method on a model asynchronously.

I suggest you take a look at `Ajax.BeginForm` - more info [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/)

You could implement a controller action on the backend which would return the text you want to display on the submitting of the form.

Comment: "You could implement a controller action on the backend which would return the text you want to display on the submitting of the form." - this was "Plan B", but, with this approach, by submitting, I reload whole page again (with text from method). I'll give Ajax a try....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **e.preventDefault()** for button click.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Click to show Tekst3" id="Show" />
</form>

Try with jQuery

 $(document).on("click", "#Show", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     faddtekst();
 });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to detail what you are implying.

Comment: No need to add "onclick=" parameter in input tag? That wouldn't work in real code, as I have to pass a parameter from button to function (thought I didn't mentioned it in question).